RedirectToAction("Index") redirect me to login page
I have a simple ASP.NET MVC application. My Edit page redirects to the login page instead of to Index. After I login again, it correctly redirects to the Index page. What am I missing?
[HttpPost]
[ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
public ActionResult Edit(SampleVM samplevm)
{
    if (!IsUserInAuthorizedRole())
    {
        return View("~/Views/Shared/Unauthorized.cshtml");
    }

    if (ModelState.IsValid)
    {
        samplevm.UserId = User.Identity.Name;
        Sample sample = PopulateSample(samplevm);
        db.Entry(sample).State = EntityState.Modified;
        db.SaveChanges();

        TempData["Message"] = "Sample has been updated.";

        //return RedirectToAction("Edit", "Samples", samplevm.SampleId);
        return RedirectToAction("Index");
    }
    
    return View(samplevm);
}

When I login, cookie is generated.  Cookie doesn't change until I click Save in Edit page.  It prompts login, then after login, cookie value is updated.
I do not modify the cookie.
// POST Create
[HttpPost]
[ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
public JsonResult SaveSamples(SampleVM samplevm)
{
    bool status = false;

    if (ModelState.IsValid)
    {
        var lotExists = SampleExists(samplevm.LotId);

        if(lotExists)
        {
            return Json(new { 
                success = false
                , status = status
                , responseText = "LotId " + samplevm.LotId + " already exists." 
            }, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
        }

        samplevm.UserId = User.Identity.Name;

        Sample sample = PopulateSample(samplevm);

        db.Samples.Add(sample);
        db.SaveChanges();
        int sampleId = sample.SampleId;

        status = true;

        return Json(new { 
            success = true
            , redirectUrl = Url.Action("Index", "Samples")
            , status = status, responseText = "Sample has been saved" 
        }, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
    }

    return new JsonResult { Data = new { status = status } };
}

// POST Edit
[HttpPost]
[ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
public ActionResult Edit(SampleVM samplevm)
{
    if (ModelState.IsValid)
    {
        samplevm.UserId = User.Identity.Name;
        Sample sample = PopulateSample(samplevm);
        db.Entry(sample).State = EntityState.Modified;
        db.SaveChanges();

        TempData["Message"] = "Sample has been updated.";

        return RedirectToAction("Index");
    }
    
    return View(samplevm);
}


Please update the question to show the request and response for all 301s and 302s that occur when you hit that endpoint.

Are you logged in when trying this edit?

It is happening because you have [Authorize] attribute on the Controller or the Index action method. When you login again, the reason why you can redirect to the Index page is because your authentication cookie is set and you can access the resource. If you expect the Edit page to redirect to Index page without login then place the attribute [AllowAnonymous] attribute on the Index action method.

@RahulSharma My Edit page also has [Authorize] attribute.  I login, I can Create.  The save on Create redirects to Index.  When I Edit, then save, it redirects to login page.  Once login again, it redirects correctly to Index.

@mjwills Yes I am login at Edit.  I have [Authorize] attribute on Index, Create and Edit methods.

@Eric Yes, that is the expected behaviour when you have [Authorize attribute placed on a Action method which is Edit in this case.  Basically you have to be logged in order to be redirected to Index page otherwise place [AllowAnonymous] on Index method to allow all types of requests to access it.

@RahulSharma But I have login before.  I login in order to Create an entry, which redirects me to Index page after saving.  I am able to go to Edit page, but after clicking save in Edit page, I have to login again before I can be redirected back to the Index page.

@Eric Are you changing your cookie after you login? Can you show us your Index and Create Action methods? Have you placed a breakpoint on this line return View("~/Views/Shared/Unauthorized.cshtml"); and see if you hit that?

Please update the question to show the request and response for all 301s and 302s that occur when you hit that endpoint. Why did you not answer my question?

Put breakpoints on every single line in Edit. Tell us which specific lines get hit.
